# Resizing UIView frame causes content to resize

Tags: ios, uiview

having some issues getting my head around resizing UIViews and drawing in drawRect. Currently I am performing some custom drawing in a UIView in the drawRect. Now I want to resize the frame but keep the drawing inside the same. Using a UISlider I have:

```
- (IBAction)changeSize:(id)sender {
    //where 20,20 is the original frame position and 72*72 the original size
    CGRect newFrame = CGRectMake(20, 20, 72*self.slider2.value, 72*self.slider2.value);
    self.square.frame = newFrame;


 }
```

The frame is growing but the contents inside are also getting stretched with it. What am I doing wrong? Any pointers on this would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self.contentMode = UIViewContentModeRedraw;`

This will cause view to redraw itself when bounds change.

Answer (score 0):

UIView contains a boolean property named autoresizesSubviews. So check out the current value and try setting it to false

```
self.square.autoresizesSubviews = NO;
```